# HealthIndicators for spring boot actuator

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

we are trying to healthcheck a spring boot application, we are planning to use spring boot actuator health to get the health status.

what is confusing is which classes provide the default healthcheck status ({"status":"UP"}) when CassandraHealthIndicator, DiskSpaceHealthIndicator, DataSourceHealthIndicator, ElasticsearchHealthIndicator,
JmsHealthIndicator, MailHealthIndicator, MongoHealthIndicator, RabbitHealthIndicator, RedisHealthIndicator, SolrHealthIndicator are not applicable.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the default is ApplicationHealthIndicator but you can of course write your own:

```
public class CustomHealthIndicator implements HealthIndicator {


    @Override
    public Health health() {
        int errorCode = check(); // perform some specific health check
        if (errorCode != 0) {
            return Health.down().withDetail("Error Code", errorCode).build();
        }
        return Health.up().build();
    }

    private int check() {

        return 0;
    }

}
```

Comment: ApplicationHealthIndicator is not getting executed during health request :(

Comment: Well according to the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/actuate/health/ApplicationHealthIndicator.html), the ApplicationHealthIndicator is the default health indicator.  If that isn't the one being called is it possible this is being overridden somewhere?

Comment: Found the answer after digging in, default health information is provided from HealthMvcEndpoint, which derives it from DiskSpaceHealthIndicator. Thanks for helping

Answer (score -1):

Found the answer after tracing the health request. Default Health information is derived from `DiskSpaceHealthIndicator`, the request for health is handled from `HealthMvcEndpoint`

Comment: That is only part of what feeds the default health check.

Comment: @DarrenForsythe what else feeds the default health check

Comment: It depends on the autoconfiguration. https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-endpoints.html#_auto_configured_healthindicators can all potentially be active

Comment: @DarrenForsythe the question says that the autoconfigured providers are not applicable.